# Melting a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
    NSW     VIC
0   6718023 5023203
1   6735528 5048207
2   6742690 5061266
3   6766133 5083593
4   6786160 5103965
```

I want to change it like this

```
0   6718023  NSW
1   6735528  NSW
2   6742690  NSW
3   6766133  NSW
4   6786160  NSW
5   5023203  VIC
6   5048207  VIC
7   5061266  VIC
8   5083593  VIC
9   5103965  VIC
```

How can i finish this job?

Comment: Classic melt question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `melt`

```
 pd.melt(df)
    Out[318]: 
      variable    value
    0      NSW  6718023
    1      NSW  6735528
    2      NSW  6742690
    3      NSW  6766133
    4      NSW  6786160
    5      VIC  5023203
    6      VIC  5048207
    7      VIC  5061266
    8      VIC  5083593
    9      VIC  5103965
```

Comment: I am wishing you a Merry Christmas! And thank you for all support, small presetn (+5). Good luck!

Comment: @jezrael happy holidays ：-）

Answer (score 4):

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
NSW    6718023
NSW    6735528
NSW    6742690
NSW    6766133
NSW    6786160
VIC    5023203
VIC    5048207
VIC    5061266
VIC    5083593
VIC    5103965
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `df.unstack`

```
df = df.unstack().to_frame().reset_index(level=0).iloc[:, [-1, 0]]
df.columns = [0, 1]   # or whatever else you please
df

         0    1
0  6718023  NSW
1  6735528  NSW
2  6742690  NSW
3  6766133  NSW
4  6786160  NSW
0  5023203  VIC
1  5048207  VIC
2  5061266  VIC
3  5083593  VIC
4  5103965  VIC
```

Answer (score 4):

**[FOMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_missing_out)**

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    value=df.values.ravel(order='F'),
    variable=df.columns.repeat(len(df))
))

     value variable
0  6718023      NSW
1  6735528      NSW
2  6742690      NSW
3  6766133      NSW
4  6786160      NSW
5  5023203      VIC
6  5048207      VIC
7  5061266      VIC
8  5083593      VIC
9  5103965      VIC
```

Comment: For completeness, you could add a `.sort_values('variable')`

Comment: Was supposed to be repeat, not tile.  no need to sort (-: