# How do I melt a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt, pandas-melt

On the [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag, I often see users asking questions about melting dataframes in pandas. I am going to attempt a [canonical Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) (self-answer) with this topic.

I am is going to clarify:

1. What is melt?
2. How do I use melt?
3. When do I use melt?

I see some hotter questions about melt, like:

- *[Convert columns into rows with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows)*: This one actually could be good, but some more explanation would be better.
- *[Pandas Melt Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830597/pandas-melt-function)*: A nice question, and the answer is good, but it's a bit too vague and doesn't have much explanation.
- *[Melting a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020139/melting-a-pandas-dataframe)*: Also a nice answer! But it's only for that particular situation, which is pretty simple, only `pd.melt(df)`
- *[Pandas dataframe use columns as rows (melt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041992/pandas-dataframe-use-columns-as-rows-melt)*: Very neat! But the problem is that it's only for the specific question the OP asked, which is also required to use `pivot_table` as well.

So I am going to attempt a canonical Q&A for this topic.

---

---

#### Dataset:

I will have all my answers on this dataset of random grades for random people with random ages (easier to explain for the answers :D):

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'John', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Alex', 'Tom'],
                   'Math': ['A+', 'B', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'C'],
                   'English': ['C', 'B', 'B', 'A+', 'F', 'A'],
                   'Age': [13, 16, 16, 15, 15, 13]})
```

```
>>> df
   Name Math English  Age
0   Bob   A+       C   13
1  John    B       B   16
2   Foo    A       B   16
3   Bar    F      A+   15
4  Alex    D       F   15
5   Tom    C       A   13
```

#### Problems:

##### Problem 1:

How do I melt a dataframe so that the original dataframe becomes the following?

```
    Name  Age  Subject Grade
0    Bob   13  English     C
1   John   16  English     B
2    Foo   16  English     B
3    Bar   15  English    A+
4   Alex   17  English     F
5    Tom   12  English     A
6    Bob   13     Math    A+
7   John   16     Math     B
8    Foo   16     Math     A
9    Bar   15     Math     F
10  Alex   17     Math     D
11   Tom   12     Math     C
```

I want to transpose this so that one column would be each subject and the other columns would be the repeated names of the students and their age and score.

##### Problem 2:

This is similar to Problem 1, but this time I want to make the Problem 1 output `Subject` column only have `Math`, I want to filter out the `English` column:

```
   Name  Age Subject Grades
0   Bob   13    Math     A+
1  John   16    Math      B
2   Foo   16    Math      A
3   Bar   15    Math      F
4  Alex   15    Math      D
5   Tom   13    Math      C
```

I want the output to be like the above.

##### Problem 3:

If I was to group the melt and order the students by their scores, how would I be able to do that, to get the desired output like the below:

```
  value             Name                Subjects
0     A         Foo, Tom           Math, English
1    A+         Bob, Bar           Math, English
2     B  John, John, Foo  Math, English, English
3     C         Tom, Bob           Math, English
4     D             Alex                    Math
5     F        Bar, Alex           Math, English
```

I need it to be ordered and the names separated by comma and also the `Subjects` separated by comma in the same order respectively.

### Problem 4:

How would I *unmelt* a melted dataframe? Let's say I already melted this dataframe:

```python
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Name', 'Age'], var_name='Subject', value_name='Grades')
```

To become:

```
    Name  Age  Subject Grades
0    Bob   13     Math     A+
1   John   16     Math      B
2    Foo   16     Math      A
3    Bar   15     Math      F
4   Alex   15     Math      D
5    Tom   13     Math      C
6    Bob   13  English      C
7   John   16  English      B
8    Foo   16  English      B
9    Bar   15  English     A+
10  Alex   15  English      F
11   Tom   13  English      A
```

Then how would I translate this back to the original dataframe, the below?

```
   Name Math English  Age
0   Bob   A+       C   13
1  John    B       B   16
2   Foo    A       B   16
3   Bar    F      A+   15
4  Alex    D       F   15
5   Tom    C       A   13
```

### Problem 5:

If I was to group by the names of the students and separate the subjects and grades by comma, how would I do it?

```
   Name        Subject Grades
0  Alex  Math, English   D, F
1   Bar  Math, English  F, A+
2   Bob  Math, English  A+, C
3   Foo  Math, English   A, B
4  John  Math, English   B, B
5   Tom  Math, English   C, A
```

I want to have a dataframe like above.

##### Problem 6:

If I was is going to completely melt my dataframe, all columns as values, how would I do it?

```
     Column Value
0      Name   Bob
1      Name  John
2      Name   Foo
3      Name   Bar
4      Name  Alex
5      Name   Tom
6      Math    A+
7      Math     B
8      Math     A
9      Math     F
10     Math     D
11     Math     C
12  English     C
13  English     B
14  English     B
15  English    A+
16  English     F
17  English     A
18      Age    13
19      Age    16
20      Age    16
21      Age    15
22      Age    15
23      Age    13
```

I want to have a dataframe like above. All columns as values.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Note for pandas versions < 0.20.0**: I will be using `df.melt(...)` for my examples, but you will need to use `pd.melt(df, ...)` instead.

#### Documentation references:

Most of the solutions here would be used with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), so to know the method [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), see [the documentation explanation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html).

> Unpivot a DataFrame from wide to long format, optionally leaving
> identifiers set.
>
> This function is useful to massage a DataFrame into a format where one
> or more columns are identifier variables *(id_vars)*, while all other
> columns, considered measured variables *(value_vars)*, are “unpivoted”
> to the row axis, leaving just two non-identifier columns, ‘variable’
> and ‘value’.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **id_vars** : *tuple, list, or ndarray, optional*
>
>   Column(s) to use as identifier variables.
> - **value_vars** : *tuple, list, or ndarray, optional*
>
>   Column(s) to unpivot. If not specified, uses all columns that are not set as id_vars.
> - **var_name** : *scalar*
>
>   Name to use for the ‘variable’ column. If None it uses frame.columns.name or ‘variable’.
> - **value_name** : *scalar, default ‘value’*
>
>   Name to use for the ‘value’ column.
> - **col_level** : *int or str, optional*
>
>   If columns are a MultiIndex then use this level to melt.
> - **ignore_index** : *bool, default True*
>
>   If True, original index is ignored. If False, the original index is retained. Index labels will be repeated
>   as necessary.
>
>   *New in version 1.1.0.*

#### Logic to melting:

Melting merges multiple columns and converts the dataframe from wide to long, for the solution to Problem 1 (see below), the steps are:

1. First we got the original dataframe.
2. Then the melt firstly merges the `Math` and `English` columns and makes the dataframe replicated (longer).
3. Then finally it adds the column `Subject` which is the subject of the `Grades` columns value, respectively:

   [image]

This is the simple logic to what the `melt` function does.

#### Solutions:

##### Problem 1:

Problem 1 could be solve using [`pd.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with the following code:

```
print(df.melt(id_vars=['Name', 'Age'], var_name='Subject', value_name='Grades'))
```

This code passes the `id_vars` argument to `['Name', 'Age']`, then automatically the `value_vars` would be set to the other columns (`['Math', 'English']`), which is transposed into that format.

You could also solve Problem 1 using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) like the below:

```
print(
    df.set_index(["Name", "Age"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index(name="Grade")
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "Subject"})
    .sort_values("Subject")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

This code sets the `Name` and `Age` columns as the index and stacks the rest of the columns `Math` and `English`, and resets the index and assigns `Grade` as the column name, then renames the other column `level_2` to `Subject` and then sorts by the `Subject` column, then finally resets the index again.

Both of these solutions output:

```
    Name  Age  Subject Grade
0    Bob   13  English     C
1   John   16  English     B
2    Foo   16  English     B
3    Bar   15  English    A+
4   Alex   17  English     F
5    Tom   12  English     A
6    Bob   13     Math    A+
7   John   16     Math     B
8    Foo   16     Math     A
9    Bar   15     Math     F
10  Alex   17     Math     D
11   Tom   12     Math     C
```

##### Problem 2:

This is similar to my first question, but this one I only one to filter in the `Math` columns, this time the `value_vars` argument can come into use, like the below:

```
print(
    df.melt(
        id_vars=["Name", "Age"],
        value_vars="Math",
        var_name="Subject",
        value_name="Grades",
    )
)
```

Or we can also use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with column specification:

```
print(
    df.set_index(["Name", "Age"])[["Math"]]
    .stack()
    .reset_index(name="Grade")
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "Subject"})
    .sort_values("Subject")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Both of these solutions give:

```
   Name  Age Subject Grade
0   Bob   13    Math    A+
1  John   16    Math     B
2   Foo   16    Math     A
3   Bar   15    Math     F
4  Alex   15    Math     D
5   Tom   13    Math     C
```

### Problem 3:

Problem 3 could be solved with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), using the `agg` function with `', '.join`, like the below:

```
print(
    df.melt(id_vars=["Name", "Age"])
    .groupby("value", as_index=False)
    .agg(", ".join)
)
```

It melts the dataframe then groups by the grades and aggregates them and joins them by a comma.

[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) could be also used to solve this problem, with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) like the below:

```
print(
    df.set_index(["Name", "Age"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "Subjects", 0: "Grade"})
    .groupby("Grade", as_index=False)
    .agg(", ".join)
)
```

This [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) function just transposes the dataframe in a way that is equivalent to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then resets the index, renames the columns and groups and aggregates.

Both solutions output:

```
  Grade             Name                Subjects
0     A         Foo, Tom           Math, English
1    A+         Bob, Bar           Math, English
2     B  John, John, Foo  Math, English, English
3     C         Bob, Tom           English, Math
4     D             Alex                    Math
5     F        Bar, Alex           Math, English
```

##### Problem 4:

> How would I unmelt a melted dataframe? Let's say I already melted this dataframe:
>
> ```
> df = df.melt(id_vars=['Name', 'Age'], var_name='Subject', value_name='Grades')
> ```

This could be solved with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html). We would have to specify the arguments `values`, `index`, `columns` and also `aggfunc`.

We could solve it with the below code:

```
print(
    df.pivot_table("Grades", ["Name", "Age"], "Subject", aggfunc="first")
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age English Math
0  Alex   15       F    D
1   Bar   15      A+    F
2   Bob   13       C   A+
3   Foo   16       B    A
4  John   16       B    B
5   Tom   13       A    C
```

The melted dataframe is converted back to the exact same format as the original dataframe.

We first pivot the melted dataframe and then reset the index and remove the column axis name.

##### Problem 5:

Problem 5 could be solved with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) like the following:

```
print(
    df.melt(id_vars=["Name", "Age"], var_name="Subject", value_name="Grades")
    .groupby("Name", as_index=False)
    .agg(", ".join)
)
```

That melts and groups by `Name`.

Or you could [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print(
    df.set_index(["Name", "Age"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .groupby("Name", as_index=False)
    .agg(", ".join)
    .rename({"level_2": "Subjects", 0: "Grades"}, axis=1)
)
```

Both codes output:

```
   Name       Subjects Grades
0  Alex  Math, English   D, F
1   Bar  Math, English  F, A+
2   Bob  Math, English  A+, C
3   Foo  Math, English   A, B
4  John  Math, English   B, B
5   Tom  Math, English   C, A
```

##### Problem 6:

Problem 6 could be solved with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and no column needed to be specified, just specify the expected column names:

```
print(df.melt(var_name='Column', value_name='Value'))
```

That melts the whole dataframe.

Or you could [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print(
    df.stack()
    .reset_index(level=1)
    .sort_values("level_1")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .set_axis(["Column", "Value"], axis=1)
)
```

Both codes output:

```
     Column Value
0       Age    16
1       Age    15
2       Age    15
3       Age    16
4       Age    13
5       Age    13
6   English    A+
7   English     B
8   English     B
9   English     A
10  English     F
11  English     C
12     Math     C
13     Math    A+
14     Math     D
15     Math     B
16     Math     F
17     Math     A
18     Name  Alex
19     Name   Bar
20     Name   Tom
21     Name   Foo
22     Name  John
23     Name   Bob
```

Comment: For the un-melt, why `pivot_table` instead of just `pivot`? There are no duplicates here.

Answer (score 6):

There is another kind of `melt` not mentioned in the question, which is that with a dataframe whose column header contains common prefix and you want to melt the suffix to column value.

It is kind of the opposite of *question 11* in [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

---

Say you have a following DataFrame, and you want to melt `1970`, `1980` to column values

```
  A1970 A1980  B1970  B1980         X  id
0     a     d    2.5    3.2 -1.085631   0
1     b     e    1.2    1.3  0.997345   1
2     c     f    0.7    0.1  0.282978   2
```

In this case you can try [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```py
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=["A", "B"], i="id", j="year")
```

```
                X  A    B
id year
0  1970 -1.085631  a  2.5
1  1970  0.997345  b  1.2
2  1970  0.282978  c  0.7
0  1980 -1.085631  d  3.2
1  1980  0.997345  e  1.3
2  1980  0.282978  f  0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

As [described by U12-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68961797/7175713), `melt`ing a dataframe primarily means reshaping the data from wide form to long form. More often than not, the new dataframe will have more rows and fewer columns compared to the original dataframe.

There are different scenarios when it comes to melting—all column labels could be melted into a single column, or multiple columns; some parts of the column labels could be retained as headers, while the rest are collated into a column, and so on. This answer shows how to melt a pandas dataframe, using `pd.stack`, `pd.melt`, `pd.wide_to_long` and [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) (I am a contributor to the pyjanitor library). The examples won't be exhaustive, but hopefully should point you in the right direction when it comes to reshaping dataframes from wide to long form.

**Sample Data**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Sepal.Length': [5.1, 5.9],
     'Sepal.Width': [3.5, 3.0],
     'Petal.Length': [1.4, 5.1],
     'Petal.Width': [0.2, 1.8],
     'Species': ['setosa', 'virginica']}
    )
```

```
df
   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width    Species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa
1           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  virginica
```

**Scenario 1 - Melt all columns:**

In this case, we wish to convert all the specified column headers into rows - this can be done with `pd.melt` or `pd.stack`, and [the solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68961797/7175713) to problem 1 already cover this. The reshaping can also be done with `pivot_longer`

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = 'Species')
```

```
     Species      variable  value
0     setosa  Sepal.Length    5.1
1  virginica  Sepal.Length    5.9
2     setosa   Sepal.Width    3.5
3  virginica   Sepal.Width    3.0
4     setosa  Petal.Length    1.4
5  virginica  Petal.Length    5.1
6     setosa   Petal.Width    0.2
7  virginica   Petal.Width    1.8
```

Just like in `pd.melt`, you can rename the `variable` and `value` column, by passing arguments to `names_to` and `values_to` parameters:

```py
df.pivot_longer(index = 'Species',
                names_to = 'dimension',
                values_to = 'measurement_in_cm')
```

```
     Species     dimension  measurement_in_cm
0     setosa  Sepal.Length                5.1
1  virginica  Sepal.Length                5.9
2     setosa   Sepal.Width                3.5
3  virginica   Sepal.Width                3.0
4     setosa  Petal.Length                1.4
5  virginica  Petal.Length                5.1
6     setosa   Petal.Width                0.2
7  virginica   Petal.Width                1.8
```

You can also retain the original index, and keep the dataframe based on order of appearance:

```py
df.pivot_longer(index = 'Species',
                names_to = 'dimension',
                values_to = 'measurement_in_cm',
                ignore_index = False,
                sort_by_appearance=True)
```

```
     Species     dimension  measurement_in_cm
0     setosa  Sepal.Length                5.1
0     setosa   Sepal.Width                3.5
0     setosa  Petal.Length                1.4
0     setosa   Petal.Width                0.2
1  virginica  Sepal.Length                5.9
1  virginica   Sepal.Width                3.0
1  virginica  Petal.Length                5.1
1  virginica   Petal.Width                1.8
```

By default, the values in `names_to` are strings; they can be converted to other data types via the `names_transform` parameter - this can be helpful/performant for large dataframes, as it is generally more efficient compared to converting the data types after the reshaping.

```py
out = df.pivot_longer(index = 'Species',
                      names_to = 'dimension',
                      values_to = 'measurement_in_cm',
                      ignore_index = False,
                      sort_by_appearance=True,
                      names_transform = 'category')

out.dtypes
```

```
Species                object
dimension            category
measurement_in_cm     float64
dtype: object
```

**Scenario 2 - Melt column labels into multiple columns:**

So far, we've melted our data into single columns, one for the column names and one for the values. However, there might be scenarios where we wish to split the column labels into different columns, or even the values into different columns. Continuing with our sample data, we could prefer to have `sepal` and `petal` under a `part` column, while `length` and `width` are into a `dimension` column:

- Via `pd.melt` - The separation is done after the melt:

  ```py
  out = df.melt(id_vars = 'Species')
  arr = out.variable.str.split('.')
  (out
  .assign(part = arr.str[0],
          dimension = arr.str[1])
  .drop(columns = 'variable')
  )
  ```

  ```
       Species  value   part dimension
  0     setosa    5.1  Sepal    Length
  1  virginica    5.9  Sepal    Length
  2     setosa    3.5  Sepal     Width
  3  virginica    3.0  Sepal     Width
  4     setosa    1.4  Petal    Length
  5  virginica    5.1  Petal    Length
  6     setosa    0.2  Petal     Width
  7  virginica    1.8  Petal     Width
  ```
- Via `pd.stack` - offers a more efficient way of splitting the columns; the split is done on the columns, meaning less number of rows to deal with, meaning potentially faster outcome, as the data size increases:

  ```py
  out = df.set_index('Species')

  # This returns a MultiIndex
  out.columns = out.columns.str.split('.', expand = True)
  new_names = ['part', 'dimension']
  out.columns.names = new_names
  out.stack(new_names).rename('value').reset_index()
  ```

  ```
       Species   part dimension  value
  0     setosa  Petal    Length    1.4
  1     setosa  Petal     Width    0.2
  2     setosa  Sepal    Length    5.1
  3     setosa  Sepal     Width    3.5
  4  virginica  Petal    Length    5.1
  5  virginica  Petal     Width    1.8
  6  virginica  Sepal    Length    5.9
  7  virginica  Sepal     Width    3.0
  ```
- Via `pivot_longer` - The key thing to note about `pivot_longer` is that it looks for patterns. The column labels are separated by a dot `.`. Simply pass a list/tuple of new names to `names_to`, and pass a separator to `names_sep` (under the hood it just uses `pd.str.split`):

  ```py
  df.pivot_longer(index = 'Species',
                  names_to = ('part', 'dimension'),
                  names_sep='.')
  ```

  ```
       Species   part dimension  value
  0     setosa  Sepal    Length    5.1
  1  virginica  Sepal    Length    5.9
  2     setosa  Sepal     Width    3.5
  3  virginica  Sepal     Width    3.0
  4     setosa  Petal    Length    1.4
  5  virginica  Petal    Length    5.1
  6     setosa  Petal     Width    0.2
  7  virginica  Petal     Width    1.8
  ```

So far, we've seen how melt, stack and pivot_longer can split the column labels into multiple new columns, as long as there is a defined separator. What if there isn't a clearly defined separator, like in the dataframe below?

```py
# https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/main/data-raw/who.csv
who = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1], 'new_sp_m5564': [2], 'newrel_f65': [3]})
who
```

```
   id  new_sp_m5564  newrel_f65
0   1             2           3
```

In the second column, we have multiple `_`, compared to the third column which has just one `_`. The goal here is to split the column labels into individual columns (`sp` & `rel` to `diagnosis` column, `m` & `f` to `gender` column, the numbers to `age` column). One option is to extract the column sub labels via a regex.

- Via `pd.melt` - again with `pd.melt`, the reshaping occurs *after* the melt:

  ```py
  out = who.melt('id')
  regex = r"new_?(?P<diagnosis>.+)_(?P<gender>.)(?P<age>\d+)"
  new_df = out.variable.str.extract(regex)
  # pd.concat can be used here instead
  out.drop(columns='variable').assign(**new_df)
  ```

  ```
     id  value diagnosis gender   age
  0   1      2        sp      m  5564
  1   1      3       rel      f    65
  ```

  Note how the extracts occurred for the regex in groups (the one in parentheses).
- Via `pd.stack` - just like in the previous example, the split is done on the columns, offering more in terms of efficiency:

  ```py
  out = who.set_index('id')
  regex = r"new_?(.+)_(.)(\d+)"
  new_names = ['diagnosis', 'age', 'gender']

  # Returns a dataframe
  new_cols = out.columns.str.extract(regex)
  new_cols.columns = new_names
  new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(new_cols)
  out.columns = new_cols
  out.stack(new_names).rename('value').reset_index()
  ```

  ```
     id diagnosis age gender  value
  0   1       rel   f     65    3.0
  1   1        sp   m   5564    2.0
  ```

  Again, the extracts occur for the regex in groups.
- Via `pivot_longer` - again we know the pattern, and the new column names, we simply pass those to the function, this time we use `names_pattern`, since we are dealing with a regex. The extracts will match the regular expression in the groups (the ones in parentheses):

  ```py
  regex = r"new_?(.+)_(.)(\d+)"
  new_names = ['diagnosis', 'age', 'gender']
  who.pivot_longer(index = 'id',
                   names_to = new_names,
                   names_pattern = regex)
  ```

  ```
     id diagnosis age gender  value
  0   1        sp   m   5564      2
  1   1       rel   f     65      3
  ```

**Scenario 3 - Melt column labels *and* values into multiple columns:**

What if we wish to split the values into multiple columns as well? Let's use a fairly [popular question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519101/simultaneously-melt-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Houston', 'Austin', 'Hoover'],
                   'State': ['Texas', 'Texas', 'Alabama'],
                   'Name':['Aria', 'Penelope', 'Niko'],
                   'Mango':[4, 10, 90],
                   'Orange': [10, 8, 14],
                   'Watermelon':[40, 99, 43],
                   'Gin':[16, 200, 34],
                   'Vodka':[20, 33, 18]},
                 columns=['City', 'State', 'Name', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Gin', 'Vodka'])
```

```
df
      City    State      Name  Mango  Orange  Watermelon  Gin  Vodka
0  Houston    Texas      Aria      4      10          40   16     20
1   Austin    Texas  Penelope     10       8          99  200     33
2   Hoover  Alabama      Niko     90      14          43   34     18
```

The goal is to collate `Mango`, `Orange`, and `Watermelon` into a fruits column, `Gin` and `Vodka` into a `Drinks` column, and collate the respective values into `Pounds` and `Ounces` respectively.

- Via `pd.melt` - I am copying [the excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520155/7175713) verbatim:

  ```py
  df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['City', 'State'],
                value_vars=['Mango', 'Orange', 'Watermelon'],
                var_name='Fruit', value_name='Pounds')
  df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['City', 'State'],
                value_vars=['Gin', 'Vodka'],
                var_name='Drink', value_name='Ounces')

  df1 = df1.set_index(['City', 'State', df1.groupby(['City', 'State']).cumcount()])
  df2 = df2.set_index(['City', 'State', df2.groupby(['City', 'State']).cumcount()])

  df3 = (pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1)
           .sort_index(level=2)
           .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
           .reset_index())
  print (df3)
  ```

  ```
        City    State       Fruit  Pounds  Drink  Ounces
  0   Austin    Texas       Mango      10    Gin   200.0
  1   Hoover  Alabama       Mango      90    Gin    34.0
  2  Houston    Texas       Mango       4    Gin    16.0
  3   Austin    Texas      Orange       8  Vodka    33.0
  4   Hoover  Alabama      Orange      14  Vodka    18.0
  5  Houston    Texas      Orange      10  Vodka    20.0
  6   Austin    Texas  Watermelon      99    NaN     NaN
  7   Hoover  Alabama  Watermelon      43    NaN     NaN
  8  Houston    Texas  Watermelon      40    NaN     NaN
  ```
- Via `pd.stack` - I can't think of a solution via stack, so I'll skip
- Via `pivot_longer` - The reshape can be efficiently done by passing the list of names to `names_to` and `values_to`, and pass a list of regular expressions to `names_pattern`- when splitting values into multiple columns, a list of regex to `names_pattern` is required:

  ```py
  df.pivot_longer(
      index=["City", "State"],
      column_names=slice("Mango", "Vodka"),
      names_to=("Fruit", "Drink"),
      values_to=("Pounds", "Ounces"),
     names_pattern=[r"M|O|W", r"G|V"],
     )
  ```

  ```
        City    State       Fruit  Pounds  Drink  Ounces
  0  Houston    Texas       Mango       4    Gin    16.0
  1   Austin    Texas       Mango      10    Gin   200.0
  2   Hoover  Alabama       Mango      90    Gin    34.0
  3  Houston    Texas      Orange      10  Vodka    20.0
  4   Austin    Texas      Orange       8  Vodka    33.0
  5   Hoover  Alabama      Orange      14  Vodka    18.0
  6  Houston    Texas  Watermelon      40   None     NaN
  7   Austin    Texas  Watermelon      99   None     NaN
  8   Hoover  Alabama  Watermelon      43   None     NaN
  ```

The efficiency is even more as the dataframe size increases.

**Scenario 4 - Group similar columns together:**

Extending the concept of melting into multiple columns, let's say we wish to group similar columns together. We do not care about retaining the column labels, just combining the values of similar columns into new columns.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_1_mean': [10],
                   'x_2_mean': [20],
                   'y_1_mean': [30],
                   'y_2_mean': [40],
                   'unit': [50]})

df
```

```
   x_1_mean  x_2_mean  y_1_mean  y_2_mean  unit
0        10        20        30        40    50
```

For the code above, we wish to combine similar columns (columns that start with the same letter) into new unique columns - all `x*` columns will be lumped under `x_mean`, while all `y*` columns will be collated under `y_mean`. We are not saving the column labels, we are only interested in the values of these columns:

- Via pd.melt - one possible way via melt is to run it via groupby on the columns:

  ```py
  out = df.set_index('unit')
  grouped = out.columns.str.split('_\d_').str.join('')
  # group on the split
  grouped = out.groupby(grouped, axis = 1)
  # iterate, melt individually, and recombine to get a new dataframe
  out = {key : frame.melt(ignore_index = False).value
         for key, frame in grouped}
  pd.DataFrame(out).reset_index()
  ```

  ```
     unit  xmean  ymean
  0    50     10     30
  1    50     20     40
  ```
- Via pd.stack - Here we split the columns and build a MultiIndex:

  ```py
  out = df.set_index('unit')
  split = out.columns.str.split('_(\d)_')
  split = [(f"{first}{last}", middle)
            for first, middle, last
            in split]
  out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(split)
  out.stack(-1).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
  ```

  ```
     unit  xmean  ymean
  0    50     10     30
  1    50     20     40
  ```
- Via pd.wide_to_long - Here we reorder the sub labels - move the numbers to the end of the columns:

  ```py
  out = df.set_index('unit')
  out.columns = [f"{first}{last}_{middle}"
                 for first, middle, last
                 in out.columns.str.split('_(\d)_')]

  (pd
  .wide_to_long(
      out.reset_index(),
      stubnames = ['xmean', 'ymean'],
      i = 'unit',
      j = 'num',
      sep = '_')
  .droplevel(-1)
  .reset_index()
  )
  ```

  ```
     unit  xmean  ymean
  0    50     10     30
  1    50     20     40
  ```
- Via pivot_longer - Again, with `pivot_longer`, it is all about the patterns. Simply pass a list of new column names to `names_to`, and the corresponding regular expressions to `names_pattern`:

  ```py
  df.pivot_longer(index = 'unit',
                  names_to = ['xmean', 'ymean'],
                  names_pattern = ['x', 'y']
                  )
  ```

  ```
     unit  xmean  ymean
  0    50     10     30
  1    50     20     40
  ```

Note that with this pattern it is on a first come first serve basis - if the column order was flipped, `pivot_longer` would give a different output. Lets see this in action:

```py
# reorder the columns in a different form:
df = df.loc[:, ['x_1_mean', 'x_2_mean', 'y_2_mean', 'y_1_mean', 'unit']]
df
```

```
   x_1_mean  x_2_mean  y_2_mean  y_1_mean  unit
0        10        20        40        30    50
```

Because the order has changed, `x_1_mean` will be paired with `y_2_mean`, because that is the first `y` column it sees, while `x_2_mean` gets paired with `y_1_mean`:

```py
df.pivot_longer(index = 'unit',
                names_to = ['xmean', 'ymean'],
                names_pattern = ['x', 'y']
                )
```

```
   unit  xmean  ymean
0    50     10     40
1    50     20     30
```

Note the difference in the output compared to the previous run. This is something to note when using names_pattern with a sequence. Order matters.

**Scenario 5 - Retain part of the column names as headers:**

This might probably be one of the biggest use cases when reshaping to long form. Some parts of the column label we may wish to keep as header, and move the remaining columns to new columns (or even ignore them).

Let's revisit our iris dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Sepal.Length': [5.1, 5.9],
     'Sepal.Width': [3.5, 3.0],
     'Petal.Length': [1.4, 5.1],
     'Petal.Width': [0.2, 1.8],
     'Species': ['setosa', 'virginica']}
    )

df
```

```
   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width    Species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa
1           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  virginica
```

Our goal here is to keep `Sepal`, `Petal` as column names, and the rest (`Length`, `Width`) are collated into a `dimension` column:

- Via pd.melt - A pivot is used *after* melting into long form:

  ```py
  out = df.melt(id_vars = 'Species')
  arr = out.variable.str.split('.')
  (out
  .assign(part = arr.str[0],
          dimension = arr.str[1])
  .pivot(['Species', 'dimension'], 'part', 'value')
  .rename_axis(columns = None)
  .reset_index()
  )
  ```

  ```
       Species dimension  Petal  Sepal
  0     setosa    Length    1.4    5.1
  1     setosa     Width    0.2    3.5
  2  virginica    Length    5.1    5.9
  3  virginica     Width    1.8    3.0
  ```

  This is not as efficient as other options below, as this involves wide to long, *then* long to wide, this might have poor performance on large enough dataframe.
- Via pd.stack - This offers more efficiency as most of the reshaping is on the columns - less is more.

  ```py
  out = df.set_index('Species')
  out.columns = out.columns.str.split('.', expand = True)
  out.columns.names = [None, 'dimension']
  out.stack('dimension').reset_index()
  ```

  ```
       Species dimension  Petal  Sepal
  0     setosa    Length    1.4    5.1
  1     setosa     Width    0.2    3.5
  2  virginica    Length    5.1    5.9
  3  virginica     Width    1.8    3.0
  ```
- Via pd.wide_to_long - Straightforward - simply pass in the relevant arguments:

  ```py
  (pd
  .wide_to_long(
      df,
      stubnames=['Sepal', 'Petal'],
      i = 'Species',
      j = 'dimension',
      sep='.',
      suffix='.+')
  .reset_index()
  )
  ```

  ```
       Species dimension  Sepal  Petal
  0     setosa    Length    5.1    1.4
  1  virginica    Length    5.9    5.1
  2     setosa     Width    3.5    0.2
  3  virginica     Width    3.0    1.8
  ```

  As the data size increases, `pd.wide_to_long` might not be as efficient.
- Via pivot_longer: Again, back to patterns. Since we are keeping a part of the column as header, we use `.value` as a placeholder. The function sees the `.value` and knows that that sub label has to remain as a header. The split in the columns can either be by `names_sep` or `names_pattern`. In this case, it is simpler to use `names_sep`:

  ```py
  df.pivot_longer(index = 'Species',
                  names_to = ('.value', 'dimension'),
                  names_sep = '.')
  ```

  ```
       Species dimension  Sepal  Petal
  0     setosa    Length    5.1    1.4
  1  virginica    Length    5.9    5.1
  2     setosa     Width    3.5    0.2
  3  virginica     Width    3.0    1.8
  ```

  When the column is split with `.`, we have `Petal, Length`. When compared with `('.value', 'dimension')`, `Petal` is associated with `.value`, while `Length` is associated with `dimension`. `Petal` stays as a column header, while `Length` is lumped into the `dimension` column. We didn't need to be explicit about the column name, we just use `.value` and let the function do the heavy work. This way, if you have lots of columns, you don't need to work out what the columns to stay as headers should be, as long as you have the right pattern via `names_sep` or `names_pattern`.

  What if we want the `Length`/`Width` as column names instead, and `Petal/Sepal` get lumped into a `part` column:
- Via pd.melt

  ```py
  out = df.melt(id_vars = 'Species')
  arr = out.variable.str.split('.')
  (out
  .assign(part = arr.str[0],
          dimension = arr.str[1])
  .pivot(['Species', 'part'], 'dimension', 'value')
  .rename_axis(columns = None)
  .reset_index()
  )
  ```

  ```
       Species   part  Length  Width
  0     setosa  Petal     1.4    0.2
  1     setosa  Sepal     5.1    3.5
  2  virginica  Petal     5.1    1.8
  3  virginica  Sepal     5.9    3.0
  ```
- Via pd.stack:

  ```py
  out = df.set_index('Species')
  out.columns = out.columns.str.split('.', expand = True)
  out.columns.names = ['part', None]
  out.stack('part').reset_index()
  ```

  ```
       Species   part  Length  Width
  0     setosa  Petal     1.4    0.2
  1     setosa  Sepal     5.1    3.5
  2  virginica  Petal     5.1    1.8
  3  virginica  Sepal     5.9    3.0
  ```
- Via pd.wide_to_long - First, we need to reorder the columns, such that `Length`/`Width` are at the front:

  ```py
  out = df.set_index('Species')
  out.columns = out.columns.str.split('.').str[::-1].str.join('.')
  (pd
  .wide_to_long(
      out.reset_index(),
      stubnames=['Length', 'Width'],
      i = 'Species',
      j = 'part',
      sep='.',
      suffix='.+')
  .reset_index()
  )
  ```

  ```
       Species   part  Length  Width
  0     setosa  Sepal     5.1    3.5
  1  virginica  Sepal     5.9    3.0
  2     setosa  Petal     1.4    0.2
  3  virginica  Petal     5.1    1.8
  ```
- Via pivot_longer:

  ```py
  df.pivot_longer(index = 'Species',
                  names_to = ('part', '.value'),
                  names_sep = '.')
  ```

  ```
       Species   part  Length  Width
  0     setosa  Sepal     5.1    3.5
  1  virginica  Sepal     5.9    3.0
  2     setosa  Petal     1.4    0.2
  3  virginica  Petal     5.1    1.8
  ```

  Notice that we did not have to do any column reordering (there are scenarios where column reordering is unavoidable), the function simply paired `.value` with whatever the split from `names_sep` gave and outputted the reshaped dataframe. You can even use multiple `.value` where applicable. Let's revisit an earlier dataframe:

  ```py
  df = pd.DataFrame({'x_1_mean': [10],
                     'x_2_mean': [20],
                     'y_1_mean': [30],
                     'y_2_mean': [40],
                     'unit': [50]})
  df
  ```

  ```
     x_1_mean  x_2_mean  y_1_mean  y_2_mean  unit
  0        10        20        30        40    50
  ```

  ```py
  df.pivot_longer(index = 'unit',
                  names_to = ('.value', '.value'),
                  names_pattern = r"(.).+(mean)")
  ```

  ```
     unit  xmean  ymean
  0    50     10     30
  1    50     20     40
  ```

It is all about seeing the patterns and taking advantage of them. `pivot_longer` just offers efficient and performant abstractions over common reshaping scenarios - under the hood it is just Pandas, [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), and Python.

Hopefully, the various answers point you in the right direction when you need to reshape from wide to long.