# How to melt the pd.dataframe with the column names as identifiers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pd.DataFrame looks like the one as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"MCD":[1,2,-2,-3, 5],
                   "AAPL":[-0.3, -0.6, 0.6, 0.9, -1.5],
                   "GOOG":[-0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3.6 , -4],
                   "MSFT":[-0.1, -0.4, 0.8, 1.1, -1.3]})
df
>>> 
    MCD  AAPL   GOOG    MSFT
 0   1   -0.3   -0.8    -0.1
 1   2   -0.6    1.6    -0.4
 2  -2    0.6    2.4     0.8
 3  -3    0.9    3.6     1.1
 4   5   -1.5   -4.0    -1.3
```

I want my dataframe to look like this by using the method `.melt`.

```
desired_df
>>>
    ticker   return
0    MCD       1
1    MCD       2
2    MCD      -2
3    MCD      -3
4    MCD       5
5    AAPL     -0.3
6    AAPL     -0.6
7    AAPL      0.6
....
18   MSFT      1.1
19   MSFT     -1.3
```

How can I turn my `df` to `desired_df` using the method `.melt` ?

p.s. One doesn't need to use `.melt` if there is a better way to answer my question. To me, `.melt` seems to be a good solution to answer my question so I just used it as an example method. :D

p.s2. My question was closed because someone claimed that there were similar questions. However, those questions do not answer my questions specifically. So I thought my question deserved to be not deleted.

Comment: `df.melt(var_name='ticker', value_name='return')`?

Comment: @Ch3steR He wants the opposite of that :)

Comment: @U12-Forward I did not get you. OP mentioned *I want my dataframe to look like this by **using the methold `.melt`**.*

Comment: @Ch3steR He's original df doesn't have the columns `'ticker'` and `'return')`.

Comment: @U12-Forward check how melt works :p

Comment: @Ch3steR I had misread *not using melt*, you should post your answer -_-'

Comment: @mozway Ah added a solution with `melt` and `T`

Comment: @mozway Well similar to my original one :P

Comment: @U12-Forward you're missusing melt, Chester's answer works literally without anything else

Comment: @mozway yeah I know, I didn't want to copy Chester's solution.

Comment: Then it's useless to add a complicated solution just for the sake of adding something @Ch3steR if you want to post as answer, let me know and I'll remove it from mine ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) like this:

```
df.melt(var_name='ticker', value_name='return')
```

Or, without melt, you can simply use `stack`, the rest is only formatting/renaming:

```
(df.rename_axis('ticker', axis=1)
   .stack()
   .rename('return')
   .reset_index(level=1)
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
   ticker  return
0     MCD     1.0
1    AAPL    -0.3
2    GOOG    -0.8
3    MSFT    -0.1
4     MCD     2.0
...
19   MSFT    -1.3
```

Comment: You don't need to use .melt if there is a better way to answer my question. To me, .melt seems to be a good solution to answer my question so I just used it as an example method. :D

Comment: Hey no need to credit me I'm sure you know how to use `.melt` ;) But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ch3steR yes, I had read the question incorrectly :p

Comment: @mozway Both got dved :P

Answer (score 1):

Use `T` and [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
>>> df.T.reset_index().melt('index', value_name='return').rename(columns={'index': 'tickers'}).drop('variable', axis=1)
   tickers  return
0      MCD     1.0
1     AAPL    -0.3
2     GOOG    -0.8
3     MSFT    -0.1
4      MCD     2.0
5     AAPL    -0.6
6     GOOG     1.6
7     MSFT    -0.4
8      MCD    -2.0
9     AAPL     0.6
10    GOOG     2.4
11    MSFT     0.8
12     MCD    -3.0
13    AAPL     0.9
14    GOOG     3.6
15    MSFT     1.1
16     MCD     5.0
17    AAPL    -1.5
18    GOOG    -4.0
19    MSFT    -1.3
>>>
```

Or you could use:

```
df.melt(var_name='ticker', value_name='return')
```

Comment: You do not need to use `.melt` if it is not the right method to solve my problem!

Comment: @Ch3steR Yeah, I wrote a cannonical about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961796/how-do-i-melt-a-pandas-dataframe) :P

Comment: @U12-Forward Yeah it's covers melt pretty good. I'll add some more variations if I find interesting/frequently asked `melt` usage.