# How to crosstab or count dataframe rows by date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to working with pandas. I have a dataframe with individual entries like this:

dfImport:

| id | date_created | date_closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01-07-2020 |  |
| 1 | 02-09-2020 | 10-09-2020 |
| 2 | 07-03-2019 | 02-09-2020 |

I would like to filter it in a way, that I get the total number of created and closed objects (count id's) grouped by Year and Quarter and Month like this:

dfInOut:

| Year | Qrt | month | number_created | number_closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | March | 1 | 0 |
| 2020 | 3 | July | 1 | 0 |
|  |  | September | 1 | 2 |

I guess I'd have to use some combination of crosstab or group_by, but I tried out alot of ideas and already did research on the problem, but I can't seem to figure out a way. I guess it's an issue of understanding. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df['date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_created'], dayfirst=True)
df['date_closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_closed'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df.melt(value_vars=['date_created','date_closed']).dropna()
df = (pd.crosstab([df1['value'].dt.year.rename('Year'), 
                   df1['value'].dt.quarter.rename('Qrt'), 
                  df1['value'].dt.month.rename('Month')], df1['variable'])
         [['date_created','date_closed']])

print (df)
variable        date_created  date_closed
Year Qrt Month                           
2019 1   3                 1            0
2020 3   7                 1            0
         9                 1            2
```

---

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   Year  Qrt  Month  date_created  date_closed
0  2019    1      3             1            0
1  2020    3      7             1            0
2  2020    3      9             1            2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked exactly as I wanted it to. Though I don't exactly understand how the crosstab function works in correlation to that .melt() function. The `df1 = df.melt(value_vars=['date_created','date_closed']).dropna()` basically just puts all entries of objects that have created dates (not nan) and closed (not nan) together and assings them either the name of "created" or "closed" right?

Comment: @Arne_22 - sorry, wrong link, I think this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961796/how-do-i-melt-a-pandas-dataframe/68961797#68961797

Comment: This is a really good explanation with a lot of examples. Seems to be a really handy function in some special cases like this. Thank you again for helping :)

Comment: @Arne_22 - you are welcome! happy coding and nice day.