# Pivot/inverse Pandas Dataframe using key pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, matrix-inverse

I have this dataframe that I would like to flip

```
        M1       M2      M3
John    0.10     0.74    0.25
Alex    0.80     0.15    0.05
```

I would like to convert it to this format:

```
        M        value    
John    M1       0.10   
John    M2       0.74
John    M3       0.25 
Alex    M1       0.80   
Alex    M2       0.15
Alex    M3       0.05
```

If there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I melt a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961796/how-do-i-melt-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, read more about `pd.melt` and you will love to use it when you are pivoting the dataframe.

As you are keeping the index while pivoting the three columns of `M`, you can do a `pd.melt` first and then do `sort_index`.

```
df.melt(value_vars = df.columns, var_name='M', ignore_index=False).sort_index(ascending=False)
Out[62]: 
       M  value
John  M1   0.10
John  M2   0.74
John  M3   0.25
Alex  M1   0.80
Alex  M2   0.15
Alex  M3   0.05
```