# Filter and rearrange a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

df:

[image]

And I need to create a DataFrame like this:

df2:

[image]

I think that it could be done using a pivot table, but im not sure how to do that.

Or there is a better way to accomplish that task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I melt a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961796/how-do-i-melt-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You can use melt: ```pd.melt(df, value_vars=["e", "f", "g", "h"], ignore_index=False)```

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: That title is really vague, and there's no actual filtering involved here. Please [edit] to clarify it. I'm thinking, "How can I make the columns of a dataframe the second level of the index?" (assuming that's what you want)

Comment: Oh, actually, is "abcd" the index, or is supposed to represent a column? Please provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={"level_0": 0, "level_1": 1, 0: 2})
print(df)

    0  1   2
0   a  e   1
1   a  f   2
2   a  g   3
3   a  h   4
4   b  e   5
5   b  f   6
6   b  g   7
7   b  h   8
8   c  e   9
9   c  f  10
10  c  g  11
11  c  h  12
12  d  e  13
13  d  f  14
14  d  g  15
15  d  h  16
```