# How to make the Data Frame into a different view?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, we have data on cities and the population in them in different years.

| City | 2000 | 2005 | 2010 | 2015 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City_1 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| City_2 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 |
| City_3 | 20 | 30 | 25 | 35 |

I need to get the DataFrame in this form:

| City | Year | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| City_1 | 2000 | 10 |
| City_1 | 2005 | 11 |
| City_1 | 2010 | 12 |
| City_1 | 2015 | 13 |
| City_2 | 2000 | 15 |
| City_2 | 2005 | 14 |
| City_2 | 2010 | 13 |
| City_2 | 2015 | 12 |
| City_3 | 2000 | 20 |
| City_3 | 2005 | 30 |
| City_3 | 2010 | 25 |
| City_3 | 2015 | 35 |

**How can this be done using Python?**

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I melt a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961796/how-do-i-melt-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `pandas.melt()` and then (how you wanted) put the results in order by city:

> This function is useful to massage a DataFrame into a format where one or more columns are identifier variables (id_vars), while all other columns, considered measured variables (value_vars), are “unpivoted” to the row axis, leaving just two non-identifier columns, ‘variable’ and ‘value’.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv.csv')
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['City'], var_name='Year', value_name='Population')
df = df.sort_values('City').set_index('City') # Sort `City` values so that they go together and set the index back to `City`
print(df)
```

```
        Year  Population
City                    
City_1  2000          10
City_1  2005          11
City_1  2010          12
City_1  2015          13
City_2  2000          15
City_2  2005          14
City_2  2010          13
City_2  2015          12
City_3  2000          20
City_3  2005          30
City_3  2010          25
City_3  2015          35
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the melt function. It's basically a reverse pivot that converts your data to a wide long format.

```
df_unpivoted = df.melt(id_vars=['City'], var_name='Year', value_name='Population')
print(df_unpivoted)
```

You can read the documentation here if you want to learn more.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html